# How do i rectify the error message i keep getting when trying to load packages?

Tags: r, package, analysis, rtools

Anytime i try loading some packages, i keep getting this error message;

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/CHERRY-1/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/ggplot2_3.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4296845 bytes (4.1 MB)
downloaded 4.1 MB
```

And the packages include the following; janitor, plotly, ggalluvial, ggpubr, gghighlight, gginnards, ggplot2, dplyr, readr, e.t.c

I have tried downloading RTools and the latest version at that, but it is still no working.